# Looking for object properties in JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm working with a results api that gives me a JSON file. With this, I need to go over the file and look for a specific property. So I push the JSON into an empty array, loop over that, and get the first object. That works great. Where I'm a bit stumped is inside of the array, all the objects from the JSON file are stored in one large object. So naturally I figured I would have to then loop over that object to get inside of it, but when I try, I get nothing back. Do I need an additional loop for this? I'll include all I can below. Also, I searched high and low for a solution to this, so apologies if this is a duplicate. If that's the case I am more than happy with a simple link to read. Thanks for your help.

JSON:

```
{  
   "0":{  
      "person_id":"001583133371",
      "source":"lexis",
      "phone_number":"",
      "first_name":"Brian",
      "middle_name":"JOSEPH",
      "last_name":"Name",
      "aliases":[  
         {  
            "first_name":"B",
            "middle_name":"",
            "last_name":"Name"
         },
         {  
            "first_name":"Brianj",
            "middle_name":"",
            "last_name":"Name"
         },
         {  
            "first_name":"Brian",
            "middle_name":"J",
            "last_name":"Name"
         },
         {  
            "first_name":"Brian",
            "middle_name":"J",
            "last_name":"Name"
         }
      ],
      "street":"",
      "city":"Newbury Park",
      "state":"CA",
      "zip":"91320",
      "priorAddresses":[  
         {  
            "street":"",
            "city":"Sacramento",
            "state":"CA"
         },
         {  
            "street":"",
            "city":"Las Cruces",
            "state":"NM"
         },
         {  
            "street":"",
            "city":"Big Bear Lake",
            "state":"CA"
         },
         {  
            "street":"",
            "city":"Camarillo",
            "state":"CA"
         }
      ],
      "age":56,
      "dob":"1958\/11\/01",
      "yob":"1958",
      "relatives":[  
         {  
            "first_name":"SHARON",
            "middle_name":"J",
            "last_name":"Name",
            "person_id":"001583349299"
         },
         {  
            "first_name":"COREY",
            "middle_name":"D",
            "last_name":"Name",
            "person_id":"036454253754"
         },
         {  
            "first_name":"KATHLEEN",
            "middle_name":"",
            "last_name":"Name",
            "person_id":"003096670145"
         },
         {  
            "first_name":"KELSEY",
            "middle_name":"MAYER",
            "last_name":"Name",
            "person_id":"080603146279"
         }
      ],
      "middle_initial":"J.",
      "gender":"m",
      "f_phone_number":"N\/A",
      "f_relatives":"Sharon Name 
Corey Name 
Kathleen Name 
Kelsey Name",
      "a_relatives":"Sharon Name,Corey Name,Kathleen Name,Kelsey Name",
      "f_priorAddresses":"Sacramento, CA;Las Cruces, NM;Big Bear Lake, CA;Camarillo, CA",
      "street_name":"",
      "street_number":"",
      "report":"fENBfE5ld2J1cnkgUGFya3xNY21haG9ufEJyaWFufDAwMTU4MzEzMzM3MXw1NnwxOTU4LzExLzAxfHw5MTMyMHxTaGFyb24gTWMgTWFob24sQ29yZXkgTWNtYWhvbixLYXRobGVlbiBNY21haG9uLEtlbHNleSBNY21haG9ufFNhY3JhbWVudG8sIENBO0xhcyBDcnVjZXMsIE5NO0JpZyBCZWFyIExha2UsIENBO0NhbWFyaWxsbywgQ0E="
   },
   "1":{  
      "person_id":"001683750301",
      "source":"lexis",
      "phone_number":"",
      "first_name":"Brian",
      "middle_name":"DANIEL",
      "last_name":"Name",
      "aliases":[  
         {  
            "first_name":"B",
            "middle_name":"",
            "last_name":"Name"
         },
         {  
            "first_name":"Brian",
            "middle_name":"Daniel",
            "last_name":"Name"
         },
         {  
            "first_name":"Brian",
            "middle_name":"Daniel",
            "last_name":"Name"
         },
         {  
            "first_name":"Brian",
            "middle_name":"",
            "last_name":"Name"
         }
      ],
      "street":"",
      "city":"Huntington Beach",
      "state":"CA",
      "zip":"92648",
      "priorAddresses":[  
         {  
            "street":"",
            "city":"Huntington Beach",
            "state":"CA"
         },
         {  
            "street":"",
            "city":"Santa Ana",
            "state":"CA"
         },
         {  
            "street":"",
            "city":"Costa Mesa",
            "state":"CA"
         },
         {  
            "street":"",
            "city":"Long Beach",
            "state":"CA"
         }
      ],
      "age":40,
      "dob":"1974\/03\/24",
      "yob":"1974",
      "relatives":[  
         {  
            "first_name":"ELAINE",
            "middle_name":"D",
            "last_name":"Name",
            "person_id":"001684063727"
         },
         {  
            "first_name":"THOMAS",
            "middle_name":"W",
            "last_name":"Name",
            "person_id":"001684361956"
         }
      ],
      "middle_initial":"D.",
      "gender":"m",
      "f_phone_number":"N\/A",
      "f_relatives":"Elaine Name 
Thomas Name",
      "a_relatives":"Elaine Name,Thomas Name",
      "f_priorAddresses":"Huntington Beach, CA;Santa Ana, CA;Costa Mesa, CA;Long Beach, CA",
      "street_name":"",
      "street_number":"",
      "report":"fENBfEh1bnRpbmd0b24gQmVhY2h8TWNtYWhvbnxCcmlhbnwwMDE2ODM3NTAzMDF8NDB8MTk3NC8wMy8yNHx8OTI2NDh8RWxhaW5lIE1jbWFob24sVGhvbWFzIE1jbWFob258SHVudGluZ3RvbiBCZWFjaCwgQ0E7U2FudGEgQW5hLCBDQTtDb3N0YSBNZXNhLCBDQTtMb25nIEJlYWNoLCBDQQ=="
   }
}

JS:

    var whereAt = [];

        $.getJSON('/search/resultsJSON/CA/this/guy', function(json) {
            whereAt.push(json);
            console.log(whereAt);
            for (var i = 0; i < whereAt.length; i++) {
                console.log(whereAt[0][i].zip);
                var test = whereAt[0][i].zip;
                    MQA.withModule('geocoder', function() {
                    map.geocodeAndAddLocations(test);
                });
                } // end for loop
            });
```

I'm trying to get the zip property for each object in the whereAt array, please don't mind the MQA stuff. The code above works, but only for getting the zip property of the first object in the array. I'm trying to find a way to grab them all and console.log them to the console. Any help I can get is greatly appreciated and if I can include anything else to help, I'm more than happy to offer whatever I can. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON is already an 'object', there's no need to push it into an array.  That JSON structure you have is more like an dictionary than array, where "0" and "1" are the keys.

try this:

```
var whereAt = json;
for (var prop in whereAt) {      
  if(whereAt.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
    console.log(whereAt[prop].zip);
  }
}
```

Also, make sure you remove those newlines characters in your "f_relatives" property.  The JSON you posted is not valid because of them.

Comment: This was it! Thank you so much. I've been hacking at this one for hours. I figured it was something that I was overthinking. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean:

```
var test = whereAt[0][i]["zip"];
```

JSON is still an array; it just has custom HR "keys" for retrieving the data.

Comment: Thanks. I gave that a try and it gives me the same as 'var test = whereAt[0][i].zip;'. That part I can dig into. It's finding the way to get the zip for each object is where I'm running into a wall.

Comment: I just ran your JSON through a [**JSON Parser**](http://json.parser.online.fr/) and it is running into an unexpected token. Are you sure your JSON is valid?

Comment: It seems to be fine actually

Comment: I just did and apparently there's an array in each object that isn't separated with comma. Guess I'll have to see what's going on there now first. Thanks for heads up on that.

Comment: Nope, it is not an array, it is a string at the moment, and when copy-pasting this JSON object to a tool like JSON lint - the string gets split over multiple lines. This one: `"f_relatives":"Elaine Mcmahon 
Thomas Mcmahon"
`, or?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need a loop for everything that is an array basically.

For instance, let's say the JSON object you provide in your example is called `jsonFile`, and  you want to go over all objects in the `jsonFile["0"]["aliases"]` array, then you would do a `for` loop with a condition like `(var i = 0; i < jsonFile["0"]["aliases"].length; i++)`.

However, if you plan on working more with JSON documents, array and Objects, I would highly recommend you check a library like [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs) or an alternative called [`underscore`](http://underscorejs.org/).

They both have a bunch of examples, and the initial little time investment into checking out the examples and figuring out the ones that you need will save you a lot of unexpected outcomes and, in general, time :)

They have functionality for doing pretty complex filtering/searching/iterative operations on the above-mentioned data types.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to recursive look through the keys of an object for a certain property you should probably use a recursive function like this:

```
function findZipCodes(obj) {
    if (typeof obj != 'object')
      return;
    if (typeof obj['zip'] != 'undefined')
      zipCodes.push(obj['zip']);
    for (prop in obj) {
      findZipCodes(obj[prop]);
    }
  }
```

Then the code to get your JSON would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var zipCodes = [];

  $.get('index.json', function(data){
    findZipCodes(data);

    function findZipCodes(obj) {
      if (typeof obj != 'object')
        return;
      if (typeof obj['zip'] != 'undefined')
        zipCodes.push(obj['zip']);
      for (prop in obj) {
        findZipCodes(obj[prop]);
      }
    }

  console.log(zipCodes);
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Your error is caused by using an index-based loop ("for (var i=0; i < ..."), and this will not work for objects with properties how you expect.  There are a number of solutions, but to alleviate your confusion about iterating on this object like an array, I recommend this code:

```
    $.getJSON('/search/resultsJSON/CA/this/guy', function(json) {
        keys = json.keys()
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            console.log(json[keys[i]].zip);
            var test = json[keys[i]].zip;
                MQA.withModule('geocoder', function() {
                map.geocodeAndAddLocations(test);
            });
            } // end for loop
        });
```

Please also see [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [For..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for reference.